# Allow null required keys in unit tests in xunit

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, unit-testing, xunit

Is it possible to allow `null` required property values in unit tests in xunit?

I am implementing the xunit approach to unit tests development described in [the abp](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Articles/Unit-Testing-with-Entity-Framework,-xUnit-Effort/index.html). In my model there is a long chain of required foreign keys for objects I am using in the arrange and act phases of unit test. Does that mean that I have to initialize the long chain every time I create a unit test or is there a way to avoid this?

In my example I have the following chain: RelationType := Template := Card := ... where A := B means that A.B is a required property.

Comment: Will your application work properly with partially setup relational chain?

Comment: @Fabio, no it won`t. I see your point. Thank you. Should I remove the question?